# Django Rest Framework where to respond 400

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have this logic that clearly doesn't belong to the `get_queryset` function, it gives me an error, where should I place this code?

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    subcategory_id = kwargs["subcategory_id"]
    retailer_id = kwargs["retailer_id"]

    try:
        subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(id=subcategory_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Response("no subcategory with that id", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I need to answer BAD_REQUEST if there isn't a subcategory object with the given id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning a response, try raising an exception, like [ValidationError](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror) or [ParseError](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#parseerror).

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    subcategory_id = kwargs["subcategory_id"]
    retailer_id = kwargs["retailer_id"]

    try:
        subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(id=subcategory_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError('no subcategory with that id')
```

However, in your case you should return a 404 because the subcategory does not exist and that is what 404 errors are for (the resource at that url does not exist). So you should raise a [NotFound](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#notfound) exception.